# WAS failed to start from RAD 9.1

Tags: java, websphere, rad

WAS doesn't start from RAD 9.1 and tt shows an exception in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
Could not find the main class: Files.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the server/Properties 
 Option: Optimize start for development/Start server with a generated script - uncheck the checkbox

It appears the generated script is not working properly.